# whay print this when replace Linux file description

Tags: linux, shell

Why it get different result? What really happened when assigning variable `a`

The shell file content is

```sh
ls
a=`cat 2 3 1>/dev/pts/0 2>/proc/self/fd/1`
echo ------$a--------1
a=`cat 2 3  2>/proc/self/fd/1 1>/dev/pts/0`
echo ------$a--------2
```

and when execute the shell , it output

```sh
[root@VM-0-17-centos ~]# sh test.sh 
2  dump.rdb  node-v12.18.3-linux-x64.tar.xz  test.sh
hello
cat: 3: No such file or directory
--------------1
hello
------cat: 3: No such file or directory--------2
```

Comment: Your question is really bad. Please include all necessarily information in your question and all steps needed to reproduce the issue. Please check your question before posting. Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I guess that the content of file `2` is `hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facts:

1. Redirections are processed *in order*.
2. Redirections are *copied*.
3. I guess that the content of file `2` is `hello` and is printed on stdout.
4. File `3` doesn't exists and the command `cat` prints `cat: 3: No such file or directory` on stderr.

Conclusions:

- `a=$(cat 2 3 1>/dev/pts/0 2>/proc/self/fd/1)`

  - `1>/dev/pts/0` binds `1` to terminal `pts/0` (why not `/dev/tty`??) which I guess is the terminal the code was run on.
  - `2>/proc/self/fd/1` is `2>&1` and it does the same, because `fd/1` is now connected to `pts/0`, this connects `2>/dev/pts/0` too.
  - `a` is empty, because both stdout and stderr of the command prints straight to terminal
- `a=$(cat 2 3  2>/proc/self/fd/1 1>/dev/pts/0)`

  - `2>/proc/self/fd/1` is the same as `2>&1` - connects stderr to where stdout points to
  - `1>/dev/pts/0` connects stdout to `pts/0`. Note that fd are *copied* - so stderr doesn't change and points to where stdout *was pointing*.
  - stdout of the command is visible on terminal (thus visible `hello`)
  - stderr of the command is connected to command substitution output so it's saved in `a`, so `cat: 3: No such file or directory` is visible.

Notes:

- Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net .
- Do not use backticks `. Use `$(...)` instead.
- Quote your variables expansions.
- Use `/dev/tty` to redirect output to controling terminal, do not use `/proc/self/fd` (nor `/dev/fd`...) and use `2>&1` instead.